# Python dataframe concatenate columns and output to nested rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have below text content in a variable called `text`

```
Page 1 Col 1 Page 1 Col 2 Page 1 Col 3

Page 2 Col 1 Page 2 Col 2 Page 2 Col 3
```

Which I am trying to add to a Python DataFrama. However, I am only interested in the rows, thus all columns should be dynamically concatenated.

This is how I add the text to a DataFrame and ultimately print it out to JSON:

```py
import pandas as pd
def textToDataFrame(text):
   dataframe = pd.read_fwf(io.StringIO(text), header=None, na_filter=False)
   dataframe = dataframe.apply(lambda x: ''.join(map(str, x)), axis=1)

   return make_response(dataframe.to_json(orient="records"))
```

This returns the following:

```
["Page 1 \u2013 Col 1.Page 1 \u2013 Col 2Page 1 \u2013 Col 3","\fPage 2 \u2013 Col 1.Page 2 \u2013 Col 2Page 2 \u2013 Col 3","\f"]
```

As you can see, the json represents *one* list, seperated by commas. However, as I said, I am only interested in the rows, so I am trying to transform the above JSON output to a nested list:

```
[["Page 1 \u2013 Col 1.Page 1 \u2013 Col 2Page 1 \u2013 Col 3"],["\fPage 2 \u2013 Col 1.Page 2 \u2013 Col 2Page 2 \u2013 Col 3","\f"]]
```

My question is - how can I make the DataFrame output consist of: one row equals one list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use -

```
op = df.apply(' '.join, axis=1)
op = op[op.str.strip() != ''].tolist()
```

**Output**

`['Page 1 Col 1 Page 1 Col 2 Page 1 Col 3', 'Page 2 Col 1 Page 2 Col 2 Page 2 Col 3']`

You can change the separator to whatever you want in the `join` statement and manipulate further for the desired json.

```
op = op[op.str.strip() != ''].apply(lambda x: [x]).tolist()
```

**Output**

```
[['Page 1 Col 1 Page 1 Col 2 Page 1 Col 3'], ['Page 2 Col 1 Page 2 Col 2 Page 2 Col 3']]
```